# put rate widget in comments

Tags: 7, comments, rating

I'm using a [rate module](http://drupal.org/project/rate) to voting widgets for nodes and comments.

I needed to put a widget on a specific place in the comments (comment.tpl.php), but I do not get it. Etou to use the following code, but the widget just does not show:

```
<?php print rate_embed($node, '_1_!', RATE_FULL); ?>
```

Comment: Try rate_generate_widget. rate_generate_widget($widget_id, $content_type, $content_id);                                 $widget_code = rate_generate_widget(1, 'comment', $comment->cid);
print $widget_code;

Comment: ths, is works..